# Laravel encrypt error

Tags: laravel

I'm moving a Laravel App to another server, and did this:

1. Copied everything to the new server.
2. Updated the database.php file.
3. Changed all occurrences of yield to _yield.

But now I'm stuck with a "Server Error: 500 (Internal Server Error)".

After a long weekend fighting with Laravel, I found where to turn on the logs and display errors. And this is what it shows:

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 22 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported Location:

/home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/laravel/crypter.php on line 40 Stack Trace:

#0 /home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/laravel/laravel.php(40): Laravel\Error::native(2, 'mcrypt_encrypt(...', '/home3/l7o1c5g8...', 40) 
#1 [internal function]: Laravel{closure}(2, 'mcrypt_encrypt(...', '/home3/l7o1c5g8...', 40, Array)
#2 /home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/laravel/crypter.php(40): mcrypt_encrypt('rijndael-256', 'YourSecretKeyGo...', 'a:3:{s:2:"id";s...', 'cbc', '5E\x9B ]\xBE\x97Yb\x98J\xD7|\xCA\x90...')
#3 /home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/laravel/session/drivers/cookie.php(40): Laravel\Crypter::encrypt('a:3:{s:2:"id";s...')
#4 /home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/laravel/session/payload.php(293): Laravel\Session\Drivers\Cookie->save(Array, Array, false)
#5 [internal function]: Laravel\Session\Payload->save()
#6 /home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/laravel/session.php(150): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/laravel/laravel.php(193): Laravel\Session::__callStatic('save', Array)
#8 /home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/laravel/laravel.php(193): Laravel\Session::save()
#9 /home3/l7o1c5g8/public_html/public/index.php(34): require('/home3/l7o1c5g8...')
#10 {main}
```

Any clue? Should I need to regenerate an encryption code? How?

No idea what to do now.

Using Laravel 3 in a shared hosting.

Comment: Your `APP_KEY` is probably not set in `.env`. You can usually do this by running `php artisan key:generate`.

Comment: Wait, Laravel 3?!

Comment: This is an old site, and theres no way to contact the developer. I have no experience with Laravel, This is the Header of the index.php file:

Comment: This is an old site, and theres no way to contact the developer. I have no experience with Laravel, This is the Header of the index.php file:  


/**
* Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
*
* package  Laravel
* version  3.2.3
* author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
* link     http://laravel.com
*/     


 ---so I asume this this Laravel 3.2.3

Comment: Also, I can find the .env file

Comment: Yeah, Laravel 3 is before they had `.env` files. Try `config/app.php` for a value called `key`.

Comment: found this:   /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Application Key
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | This key is used by the encryption and cookie classes to generate secure
 | encrypted strings and hashes. It is extremely important that this key
 | remain secret and should not be shared with anyone. Make it about 32
 | characters of random gibberish.
 |
 */

 'key' => 'YourSecretKeyGoesHere!',

Comment: Yeah, so you're going to want to put a 32 random character string in there.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I changed the default key on /public_html/application/config/application.php

from:   'key' => 'YourSecretKeyGoesHere!',

to:     'key' => '32 characters!',

you must replace the default key with a 16,24 or 32 characters word.

Thank you for your help.